# New field with the date of the subsequent row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID      Name           Request Date
296459  Waiting        2016-06-04 22:53:46.000
296459  ED-22          2016-06-04 23:01:30.650
296459  CCS-CC28-A     2016-06-05 01:16:00.000
296459  4N-N450-A      2016-06-14 06:33:41.530
```

I would like to create a new row called End Date which would contain the Request Date from the next row.

```
ID        Name           Request Date             End Date
296459  Waiting        2016-06-04 22:53:46.000  2016-06-04 23:01:30.650
296459  ED-22          2016-06-04 23:01:30.650  2016-06-05 01:16:00.000
296459  CCS-CC28-A     2016-06-05 01:16:00.000  2016-06-14 06:33:41.530
296459  4N-N450-A      2016-06-14 06:33:41.530  GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, use `lead` to get the values on the next row (based on a specified ordering)

```
select t.*, 
coalesce(lead(request_date) over(partition by id order by request_date), getdate()) as end_date
from tablename t
```

Comment: Nailed it. I few seconds before I send my answer :) +1